# Is there any Lifetime in either RxJava or RxKotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, reactive-programming

[JetBrains/rd](https://github.com/JetBrains/rd/) library has a concept of [`Lifetime`](https://github.com/JetBrains/rd/blob/master/rd-core/src/commonMain/kotlin/com/jetbrains/rider/util/lifetime/RLifetime.kt#L20) which can be thought of as an inverted version of `AutoCloseable` or `IDisposeable` (see [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/sdk/Platform/Lifetime.html) and [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/sdk/HowTo/WorkWithLifetime.html) for more details).

The simplest use-case example would be smth like this:

```
import com.jetbrains.rider.util.lifetime.Lifetime
import com.jetbrains.rider.util.lifetime.onTermination
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.InputStream

class LifetimeExample(lifetime: Lifetime, private val input: InputStream) {
    init {
        lifetime.onTermination {
            input.close()
            println("File closed.")
        }
    }

    fun process() {
        println("${input.bufferedReader().readText().length} char(s) read.")
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(vararg args: String) {
            Lifetime.using {
                LifetimeExample(it, FileInputStream("/etc/passwd")).process()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any similar concept in either [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) or [RxKotlin](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin)?

Comment: Just to clarify, you don't mean Android lifecycle right?

Comment: @GilGoldzweig Assuming I'm totally unaware of Android development, the answer is most probably no.